# How to use Facebook Javascript SDK with partial pipeline in Python Social Auth?

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I am trying to set up PSA using Facebook Javascript SDK.

I want to use partial pipeline so that user is redirected to a form that collects additional data.

Example in the docs is geared towards ajax authentication which is not what I want. Here is code that I have so far that works for users that don't need to be redirected.

```
# could not get decorator to work with cbv :(
@psa('social:complete')
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    token = request.GET.get('access_token')
    backend = request.backend
    user = backend.do_auth(token)
    return user


class RegisterByTokenView(View):

    def get(self, request, backend):
        user = register_by_access_token(request, backend)
        if user:
            login(request, user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

There are a couple of things that are not working for me.

1. If user needs to be redirected through partial pipeline `register_by_access_token` will return HTTPResponseRedirect which will cause `login(request, user)` to fail.
2. Even if pipeline skips partial pipeline and my user is authenticated properly I am not sure how to get the user to end up in the url that was specified in `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL`.